# how to move files in different sub-directories?

Tags: python, file, for-loop, directory, shutil

i have a directory with files with different extensions, i have to move these files in their folder (creating them) inside the "files directory", i write that but i need help (first project please be gentle)

```py
import os
import shutil

os.makedirs("C:\\FileOrganizer\\FileOrganizer\\Files\\Images")
os.makedirs("C:\\FileOrganizer\\FileOrganizer\\Files\\Text")
os.makedirs("C:\\FileOrganizer\\FileOrganizer\\Files\\Mp3")

src_fldr = "C:\\FileOrganizer\\FileOrganizer\\Files"
fldr_img ="C:\\FileOrganizer\\FileOrganizer\\Files\\Images"
fldr_txt = "C:\\FileOrganizer\\FileOrganizer\\Files\\Text"
fldr_mp3 = "C:\\FileOrganizer\\FileOrganizer\\Files\\Mp3"

for file in os.listdir(src_fldr): 
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".txt", ".otd"):
        shutil.move(src_fldr, fldr_txt)
    elif filename.endswith(".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png"):
        shutil.move(src_fldr, fldr_img)
    elif filename.endswith(".mp3"):
        shutil.move(src_fldr, fldr_mp3)
    else: 
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the source file instead of the source folder into the destination folder

```py
for file in os.listdir(src_fldr): 
    filename = os.fsdecode(file) # remove me
    if filename.endswith(".txt", ".otd"):
        shutil.move(file, fldr_txt)
    elif filename.endswith(".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png"):
        shutil.move(file, fldr_img)
    elif filename.endswith(".mp3"):
        shutil.move(file, fldr_mp3)
    else: 
        pass
```

also, I think you should remove the `os.fsdecode` entire line and change use `file` directly

```py
if file.endswith(".txt", ".otd"):
```

Comment: and write the code like `if file.endswith(...) ...` ?

Comment: yes, because `listdir` returns a list of filenames already